# image compression through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, compression, filereader

I have a requirement where i have to upload an image and display both thumbnail and full size image.

When the user right clicks and saves the thumbnail, the thumbnail image should be save(less size).

Here is my HTML

```
<input type='file' accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'><br>
    <img id='output' width="150" height="150">
    <img id='output1'>
```

Here is my script

```
var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var output1 = document.getElementById('output1');
        output.src = dataURL;
        output1.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: Saved? Where? How? What is the actual question here?

Comment: from the HTML page to the hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this approach using canvas. It will actually reduce the image size.

```
output.src = dataURL;
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width=150
canvas.height=150
ctx.drawImage(output, 0, 0, 150, 150);
output.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```